# Why does my display function terminate the program?

Tags: c++, linked-list

So I've been working on this program all day, so I may just be burnt out, but for the life of me I can't figure out why my display function terminates the program once it's done printing the first time. I really need to be able to print the entire list on each input loop. I've tried debugging it by wrapping it in a loop and adding print statements to test and the whole program runs fine except for the fact that after I print the list it terminates.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node
{
public:
    int data;
    Node *next;
    Node()
    {
        next = 0;
    }
    Node(int data)
    {
        this->data = data;
    }
};

class list
{
private:
    int Count = 0;
    Node *start;

public:
    list()
    {
        start = 0;
    }

    void display()
    {
        Node *temp = new Node;
        temp = start;

        while (temp != 0)
        {
            cout << temp->data << " ";
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }

    bool insert(int value)
    {
        Node *newNode = new Node(value);
        Node *temp = new Node;
        Node *cur = new Node;
        Node *pre = new Node;
        int track = 0;
        cur = start;

        if (start == 0)
        {
            start = newNode;
            Count++;
        }
        else if (value < cur->data)
        {
            temp->data = value;
            temp->next = start;
            start = temp;
            Count++;
        }
        else
            for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
            {
                if (value > cur->data)
                {
                    pre = cur;
                    cur = cur->next;
                    track++;
                }
            }
        if (track > 0)
        {
            temp->data = value;
            pre->next = temp;
            temp->next = cur;
            Count++;
        }
        return true;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    int input = 0;
    list obj;

    while (input != -1)
    {
        cout << "Enter a value: ";
        cin >> input;
        if (input != -1)
            obj.insert(input);
        obj.display();
    }

}
;
```

Comment: `Node *temp = new Node; temp = ...` is a memory leak. You've just lost the only pointer to the new Node object you allocated.

Comment: The cause of the problem (at least, the one you asked about - it's not the only problem) is actually in your `insert()` function.    It doesn't set things up in the way that `display()` expects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    Node(int data){this->data=data;}
```

Your `Node` constructor that takes an `int` only initializes `data`, but not `next`.

So in

```
    Node *newNode=new Node(value);
```

`newNode` points to a `Node` with a garbage `next` pointer.

The first time through `insert()` you enter this branch:

```
    if(start==0){
        start = newNode;
```

The following call to `display()` then executes this code:

```
    temp=start;

    while(temp!=0){
        cout<<temp->data<<" ";
        temp=temp->next;  // Bang! temp->next is garbage.
```

The last line has undefined behavior: You're trying to use an uninitialized pointer value and assign it to `temp`. This will probably crash in `cout<<temp->data` (in the next iteration of the loop) at the latest.